# IllegalStateException while launching JUnit test with OSGi

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, osgi

I have some strange problem in one of my projects. I am trying to run some JUnit test in an OSGi environment (tests are in a fragment hosted by an osgi bundle ; operation is launched with the "JUnit Plug-in Test" launcher from eclipse). When I try to launch the test, I get the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the    org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
An error has occurred. See the log file
```

In the log above I get also :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-08-22 13:53:24.058
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-08-22 13:53:24.059
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:/C:/.../plugins/org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime_3.4.200.v20120530-1435.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime 2 0 2012-08-22 13:53:24.059
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
```

However, `org.eclipse.core.runtime` seems to be available (eclipse is running without any problems and I can launch the project using an OSGi run). According to the "Eclipse Installation Details", the core runtime has the version 3.8.0.v20120521-2346 that is in the correct range required by junit (`[3.3.0,4.0.0)`).

I have also an other identical eclipse (same versions etc... it comes from the same .zip archive) where I can run the same kind of tests for another project. I have checked the configurations and I wasn't able to find any difference. Thus I am currently unable to understand what can cause this issue.

Thanks a lot in advance for any idea that could help me to solve that,

Comment: are you doing unit or inter-service integration test using junit? for unit test you should have no dependencies on the OSGi subsystem. For the latter, there are several options...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The test I am currently trying to run are only calling internal routines of the host bundle. I am not trying to do inter-service integration but I am not sure it will impact much on my current problem. Indeed, my error seems to come from the eclipse junit plugin ("org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime") that try to use the core runtime but do not find it.

Comment: are you running your junit test with the junit runner or with the 'Junit Plug-in Test'  runner ?  You should not be involved with the osgi env in a simple Junit test.

Comment: I am really sorry because I am maybe realizing that my first explanations wasn't good. I am running it with "Junit Plug-in Test" runner. I am testing an OSGi application and I use a test fragment hosted by the bundle I want to test. My test does not involve exactly inter-service integration but I need to be in an OSGi env. I have already tested OSGi applications in this way many times without any problem.

Comment: we also separate the tests from the prod code using fragments, but we use the junit launcher to run the tests. Do you have some dependencies on the OSGi runtime? If not, you don't need the 'Junit Plugin test'.

Comment: Actually some of the method tested are using some dependencies to the core osgi framework through the Activator (org.osgi.framework.*) (call to Activator.getContext().getBundle().getEntry()...) so I am not sure it will work with the JUnit launcher (I can't test right now). I will try anyway because it should be quite faster for the test that does not involve inter-bundle operations. I will try anyway to understand what could prevent the "JUnit Plug-in launcher" to work because it should be ok in all cases.

Comment: Well, I don't use the Activator as I prefer DS injection instead. For resource location, you can use the `public void activate(ComponentContext context)` version of the activate method to inject a mock context to your service.

Comment: for issues with the  "JUnit Plug-in launcher"  have a look at the start-up order of bundles, and also what bundles are included in your test definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip of the mock context. I didn't know that. For the bundles launched, they are basically the same as in my regular launch but I will recheck that. Actually the error does not involve the dependencies of my bundles but of the junit plugin from eclipse and that's quite strange. This kind of error "core runtime" not found usually happen when the start of eclipse itself fails (not in my case but based on web investigations)

Comment: Vainilla junit will run faster than bringing the OSGi env up for each test. From the stack trace, it looks like your plugin configuration for a 'JUnit plugin test'  is incomplete. I'll put some of this info in a proper answer for future references.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like some bundles are missing in your JUnit Plugin Test configuration. You can use the `Validate Plug-ins` function on  the `Plugins` page to check whether your configuration is complete. Beware: I've had some cases of dependency creep with this method, usually from some 'innocent' eclipse runtime plugin that should not have been there in the first place.

That said, if you would use DS (Declarative Services), you can eliminate all dependencies on the OSGi API, and therefore use vainilla JUnit to test your code. 
One particularly hidden treasure of DS is this service activate signature `public void activate(ComponentContext context)` that allows you to inject a `ComponentContext` to your service. Using mocks (we use Mockito) you can mock any required call to e.g. load resources.

Likewise, you can mock all services as they can be injected through their lifecycle methods (bind, unbind) as declared in the  `osgi-inf` descriptors (we use Equinox):

```
<reference interface="com.service.itf" name="UsefulService"  cardinality="1..1" policy="static" bind="onDependencyServiceUp"  unbind="onDependencyServiceDown"/>
```

Then, on your unit test preparation, you can simply declare a Mock and use the bind method to inject it.

This will make your testing efforts within OSGi a lot easier, as you will not have to create and maintain a bundle configuration for each test and, at the same time, vainilla Junit test run a lot faster.

For inter-bundle integration & system tests you can then opt for the `Junit plugin test` or look into [Pax Exam](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Pax+Exam).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer which is really interesting and add several meaningful points. For the configuration itself, I am using the exact same configuration for my "normal" OSGi runs (i.e same plugins with the same start order) and I don't get any error. Moreover, the unresolved dependency is something linked with the eclipse runtime itself and that's is quite strange. I will accept your answer as soon as I will be sure that there is no other external problem (if there's another problem, I will post it here so we could centralize the knowledge in an unique post).